# spring-boot fat jar with h2 driver unable to build graalvm native image

Tags: spring-boot, h2, graalvm-native-image

I failed to convert a spring-boot fat jar with h2 driver into graalvm native image, following is the exception message:

`Excluding 0 auto-configurations from spring.factories file
Processing existing META-INF/spring.components files...
Registered 15 entries
Configuring initialization time for specific types and packages:
#87 buildtime-init-classes   #23 buildtime-init-packages   #33 runtime-init-classes    #1 runtime-init-packages

Error: Incompatible change of initialization policy for org.springframework.boot.validation.MessageInterpolatorFactory: trying to change RUN_TIME from the command line to BUILD_TIME from feature org.springframework.graalvm.support.InitializationHandler.register
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Incompatible change of initialization policy for org.springframework.boot.validation.MessageInterpolatorFactory: trying to change RUN_TIME from the command line to BUILD_TIME from feature org.springframework.graalvm.support.InitializationHandler.register
    at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:68)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationConfiguration.insertRec(ClassInitializationConfiguration.java:98)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationConfiguration.insertRec(ClassInitializationConfiguration.java:112)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationConfiguration.insertRec(ClassInitializationConfiguration.java:112)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationConfiguration.insertRec(ClassInitializationConfiguration.java:112)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationConfiguration.insertRec(ClassInitializationConfiguration.java:112)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationConfiguration.insertRec(ClassInitializationConfiguration.java:112)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationConfiguration.insert(ClassInitializationConfiguration.java:63)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ConfigurableClassInitialization.initializeAtBuildTime(ConfigurableClassInitialization.java:392)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.hosted.RuntimeClassInitialization.initializeAtBuildTime(RuntimeClassInitialization.java:118)
    at org.springframework.graalvm.support.InitializationHandler.register(InitializationHandler.java:52)
    at org.springframework.graalvm.support.SpringFeature.beforeAnalysis(SpringFeature.java:79)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$runPointsToAnalysis$7(NativeImageGenerator.java:679)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.forEachFeature(FeatureHandler.java:70)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:679)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:538)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$run$0(NativeImageGenerator.java:451)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 24.097 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-27T11:41:49+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 53M/1388M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------`

I did run it with agent first to obtain config files and include "-H:ConfigurationResourceRoots=nativeimage" in native-image-maven-plugin configuration.

The modules version used in my build environment:

```
native-image-maven-plugin: 20.1.0
spring-graalvm-native: 0.7.0
graal-sdk: 20.1.0
spring-boot-starter-parent: 2.3.0.RELEASE
spring-context-indexer
```

Can this be solved by configuration or else?

EDIT @ 2020/07/01 --
Got the following error with
spring-boot-starter-parent:2.4.0-SNAPSHOT
spring-graalvm-native:0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
and

```
<buildArgs>-H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -H:+TraceClassInitialization --allow-incomplete-classpath -H:+RemoveSaturatedTypeFlows -R:MaxHeapSize=16g -J-Xmx16G</buildArgs>
```

```
Warning: class initialization of class org.springframework.boot.validation.MessageInterpolatorFactory failed with exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidationException. This class will be initialized at run time because option --allow-incomplete-classpath is used for image building. Use the option --initialize-at-run-time=org.springframework.boot.validation.MessageInterpolatorFactory to explicitly request delayed initialization of this class.
Number of types dynamically registered for reflective access: #2826
[com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4160331]     analysis:  68,477.47 ms,  5.20 GB
Error: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:
 com.alibaba.druid.mock.MockDriver was unintentionally initialized at build time. org.h2.Driver caused initialization of this class with the following trace: 
    at com.alibaba.druid.mock.MockDriver.<clinit>(MockDriver.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:603)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.loadInitialDrivers(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.<clinit>(DriverManager.java:101)
    at org.h2.Driver.load(Driver.java:155)
    at org.h2.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java:41)

com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver was unintentionally initialized at build time. org.h2.Driver caused initialization of this class with the following trace: 
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.<clinit>(NonRegisteringDriver.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:603)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.loadInitialDrivers(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.<clinit>(DriverManager.java:101)
    at org.h2.Driver.load(Driver.java:155)
    at org.h2.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java:41)

com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver was unintentionally initialized at build time. org.h2.Driver caused initialization of this class with the following trace: 
    at com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver.<clinit>(FabricMySQLDriver.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:603)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.loadInitialDrivers(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.<clinit>(DriverManager.java:101)
    at org.h2.Driver.load(Driver.java:155)
    at org.h2.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java:41)

com.alibaba.druid.proxy.DruidDriver was unintentionally initialized at build time. org.h2.Driver caused initialization of this class with the following trace: 
    at com.alibaba.druid.proxy.DruidDriver.<clinit>(DruidDriver.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:603)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.loadInitialDrivers(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.<clinit>(DriverManager.java:101)
    at org.h2.Driver.load(Driver.java:155)
    at org.h2.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java:41)

com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was unintentionally initialized at build time. org.h2.Driver caused initialization of this class with the following trace: 
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:603)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.loadInitialDrivers(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.<clinit>(DriverManager.java:101)
    at org.h2.Driver.load(Driver.java:155)
    at org.h2.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java:41)


com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:
 com.alibaba.druid.mock.MockDriver was unintentionally initialized at build time. org.h2.Driver caused initialization of this class with the following trace: 
    at com.alibaba.druid.mock.MockDriver.<clinit>(MockDriver.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:603)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.loadInitialDrivers(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.<clinit>(DriverManager.java:101)
    at org.h2.Driver.load(Driver.java:155)
    at org.h2.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java:41)

com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver was unintentionally initialized at build time. org.h2.Driver caused initialization of this class with the following trace: 
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.<clinit>(NonRegisteringDriver.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:603)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.loadInitialDrivers(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.<clinit>(DriverManager.java:101)
    at org.h2.Driver.load(Driver.java:155)
    at org.h2.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java:41)

com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver was unintentionally initialized at build time. org.h2.Driver caused initialization of this class with the following trace: 
    at com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver.<clinit>(FabricMySQLDriver.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:603)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.loadInitialDrivers(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.<clinit>(DriverManager.java:101)
    at org.h2.Driver.load(Driver.java:155)
    at org.h2.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java:41)

com.alibaba.druid.proxy.DruidDriver was unintentionally initialized at build time. org.h2.Driver caused initialization of this class with the following trace: 
    at com.alibaba.druid.proxy.DruidDriver.<clinit>(DruidDriver.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:603)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.loadInitialDrivers(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.<clinit>(DriverManager.java:101)
    at org.h2.Driver.load(Driver.java:155)
    at org.h2.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java:41)

com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was unintentionally initialized at build time. org.h2.Driver caused initialization of this class with the following trace: 
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:603)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.loadInitialDrivers(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.<clinit>(DriverManager.java:101)
    at org.h2.Driver.load(Driver.java:155)
    at org.h2.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java:41)


    at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:68)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ConfigurableClassInitialization.checkDelayedInitialization(ConfigurableClassInitialization.java:518)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationFeature.duringAnalysis(ClassInitializationFeature.java:187)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$runPointsToAnalysis$8(NativeImageGenerator.java:720)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.forEachFeature(FeatureHandler.java:70)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:720)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:538)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$run$0(NativeImageGenerator.java:451)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

EDIT @ 2020/07/02 --
I got the following error when I tried to init the "unintentionally initialized" classes at build time.

```
Warning: class initialization of class org.springframework.boot.validation.MessageInterpolatorFactory failed with exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidationException. This class will be initialized at run time because option --allow-incomplete-classpath is used for image building. Use the option --initialize-at-run-time=org.springframework.boot.validation.MessageInterpolatorFactory to explicitly request delayed initialization of this class.
Number of types dynamically registered for reflective access: #2824
[com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1276846]     (clinit):   1,639.21 ms,  6.48 GB
[com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1276846]   (typeflow):  41,244.42 ms,  6.48 GB
[com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1276846]    (objects):  34,338.05 ms,  6.48 GB
[com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1276846]   (features):   9,918.59 ms,  6.48 GB
[com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1276846]     analysis:  89,221.06 ms,  6.48 GB
Error: Unsupported features in 2 methods
Detailed message:
Error: type is not available in this platform: org.graalvm.compiler.hotspot.management.SVMMBean
Trace: Object was reached by 
    reading field com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.NamedObject.object of
        constant com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.NamedObject@4e61fbc2 reached by 
    reading field java.util.HashMap$Node.value of
        constant java.util.HashMap$Node@41a5eec0 reached by 
    reading field java.util.HashMap$Node.next of
        constant java.util.HashMap$Node@4a321ac0 reached by 
    indexing into array
        constant java.util.HashMap$Node[]@5ec2c4b0 reached by 
    reading field java.util.HashMap.table of
        constant java.util.HashMap@441dc7c0 reached by 
    reading field java.util.HashMap$Node.value of
        constant java.util.HashMap$Node@8f15e1fa reached by 
    indexing into array
        constant java.util.HashMap$Node[]@2a17237f reached by 
    reading field java.util.HashMap.table of
        constant java.util.HashMap@5eace3ce reached by 
    reading field com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.domainTb of
        constant com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository@1397c899 reached by 
    reading field com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.repository of
        constant com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor@1a8e83d1 reached by 
    reading field com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.mbsInterceptor of
        constant com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@1d840f77 reached by 
    reading field java.lang.ref.Reference.referent of
        constant com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.WeakIdentityHashMap$IdentityWeakReference@1d840f77 reached by 
    reading field java.util.HashMap$Node.key of
        constant java.util.HashMap$Node@61056459 reached by 
    indexing into array
        constant java.util.HashMap$Node[]@1db861a7 reached by 
    reading field java.util.HashMap.table of
        constant java.util.HashMap@61056459 reached by 
    reading field com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.WeakIdentityHashMap.map of
        constant com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.WeakIdentityHashMap@53bb4e30 reached by 
    scanning method com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanLookup.lookupFor(MXBeanLookup.java:93)
Call path from entry point to com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanLookup.lookupFor(MBeanServerConnection): 
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanLookup.lookupFor(MXBeanLookup.java:93)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:162)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:258)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy282.duplicate(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl$CancelTask$1.run(StatementImpl.java:124)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:517)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:193)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.PosixJavaThreads_pthreadStartRoutine_e1f4a8c0039f8337338252cd8734f63a79b5e3df(generated:0)
```

this repeats 6 times with different call paths.

Comment: Hey James, could you please add your pom.xml including the native-image-maven-plugin configuration? I guess you need to play around with the `--initialize-at-run-time` or `--initialize-at-build-time` parameters... but it's strange, that the mentioned class in the stacktrace is a Spring class. Also try the newest releases of Spring Boot and the spring-graalvm-native projects you can get (at least Boot has `2.3.1.RELEASE` and the Spring Graal Feature `0.7.1`). Ah, and could you please elaborate why you choose to run the native image agent first - and not just rely on the Spring Graal Feature?!

Comment: Hi jonashackt, no luck with spring-graalvm-native:0.7.1 and spring-boot-starter-parent:2.3.1.RELEASE

following is the buildArgs for native-image-maven-plugin:

--allow-incomplete-classpath --no-fallback --enable-all-security-services -H:ConfigurationResourceRoots=nativeimage -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime --initialize-at-run-time=org.springframework.boot.validation.MessageInterpolatorFactory --initialize-at-build-time=org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize -H:+TraceClassInitialization --no-server -R:MaxHeapSize=16g -J-Xmx16G

Comment: native image agent is used to resolve lots of Autowired and Resource and create config files (jni-config.json, proxy-config.json, reflect-config.json, resource-config.json) for the build.

Comment: Hmm, I would give it a try without the separate native image agent - and configure it like in this example: https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-graalvm-native/tree/master/spring-graalvm-native-samples/vanilla-orm - see the pom.xml there, h2 is also used - and you can see the configuration of the native image command in the `compile.sh` script (it uses `-H:+RemoveSaturatedTypeFlows` and `-Dspring.native.remove-yaml-support=true`, but nothing of your configuration).

Comment: FYI: `--no-server`, `--no-fallback`, `--allow-incomplete-classpath` are now default options since `spring-graalvm-native 0.7.0`, so you can leave them out - for more details see my latest post https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2020/06/spring-boot-graalvm-native-image-maven-plugin/ or the [latest docs](https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/experimental/spring-graalvm-native-docs/0.7.1/spring-graalvm-native-docs-0.7.1.zip!/reference/index.html#_options_enabled_by_default)

Comment: @jonashackt, no luck with spring-boot-starter-parent:2.4.0-SNAPSHOT and spring-graalvm-native:0.8.0-SNAPSHOT used in vanilla-orm sample

Comment: Did you try without the native image agent - and just let spring-graalvm-native Feature do the processing?

Comment: the update was done without native image agent

Comment: Very strange! Well as a h2 example project is already working (as shown in the mentioned sample projects), further help is only possible, if you share comprehensible example project with code and pom.xml configuration. Maybe it's already an OpenSource project - otherwise you could maybe extract an example project to GitHub without all the enterprise specific settings/data. I could also recommend this approach, it would not only help you - but many other folks to understand the problem in advance.

Comment: I believe this is the minimum set to reproduce the error (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lzeTynPSqrrgnuxjD1TwibFaefFp4Lap/view?usp=sharing)